# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory not loading on Azure DevOps PowerShell Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell

Recently I experienced some issue with Azure DevOps PowerShell when attempting to create a ClientCredential and or ClientAssertion. I have the following code which was working on the past for creating a ClientCredential based on the following variables:

1. TenantId
2. ClientID (SPN)
3. Password (SPN Password)

   $ResourceUrl = "https://database.windows.net/"

   $AuthorityUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TenantId)"

   $objClientCredential = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential]::new($ClientId, $Password)
   $objAuthenticationContext = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]::new($AuthorityUrl)
   $objAuthenticationResult = $objAuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync($ResourceUrl, $objClientCredential)

but recently this code stop working. It seems that the AzureAD module is not loading correctly. This only happens on Azure DevOps Powershell, on my machine it works fine (I am using PowerShell 7.1)
So far so now I attempted the following:

1. Run the code as shown above
   **Breaks on: **$objClientCredential = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential]::new($ClientId, $Password)
   **Error:** Unable to find type [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential]
2. Install AzureAD before running the code
   Install-Module -Name AzureAD -Force
   Import-Module -Name AzureAD
   **Breaks on: **$objClientCredential = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential]::new($ClientId, $Password)
   **Error:** Unable to find type [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential]
3. Import the dll Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll from my machine
   Add-Type -Path ".\libraries\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll
   Doesn't break, however ClientCredential is not created it is returned as null

Have anyone experienced a similar issue? Do you know how should I drive this?

Answer (score 1):

If you run the scripts on local machine. You can check where the assembly is installed and manually import the .dll file. I tested on my local machine. It works fine when i just import the azureAd module:

```
Install-Module AzureAD -Force 
Import-Module -Name AzureAD
```

If you are run the script in azure pipeline. When you install `AzureAD` module using `Install-Module -Name AzureAD -Force` in azure powershell task . You can see from the build log that AzureAD module is installed in folder `C:\Program  Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureAD\2.0.2.128`:

[image]

And from the log, we can see assembly `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll` doesnot get loaded automatically.

So you can manually load it from module Azure AD installation folder: See below:

```
Install-Module AzureAD -Force 
Import-Module -Name AzureAD
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureAD\2.0.2.128\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
    
$TenantId= "..."

$ClientID ="..."

$Password = "..."
$ResourceUrl = "https://database.windows.net/"

$AuthorityUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TenantId)"
...
$objAuthenticationResult = $objAuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync($ResourceUrl, $objClientCredential).Result
```

See below result.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution Install-Module AzureAD -Force, Import-Module AzureAD Add-Type xxxxxx, but I get the same results that when I used the dll from my machine. The code doesn't throw an exception at ClientCredential creation, but it returns a null

Comment: @delucaezequiel I checked your code and found you used the async method `AcquireTokenAsync`. Async methold didnot return the result immediately. You need to get the result by revoking the Result property. `$objAuthenticationResult = $objAuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync($ResourceUrl, $objClientCredential).Result`. See above update

Comment: The AcquireTokenAsync can not execute properly as the ClientCredentials are null. After $objAuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync($ResourceUrl, $objClientCredential) I return the access token with $objAuthenticationContext.Result.AccessToken, but as I said it never executes properly due to ClientCredentials in null

Comment: @delucaezequiel did you check if the $ClientId, $Password were successfully passed to the `new()` methold?

Comment: Yes, I did. They arrive with the desired values. I print them in console before execution and copy to a text plain file to check that no empty spaces were added by mistake.