# Cant load a particular module in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, powershell-module

I am trying to use
`[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]` as follows:

```
$authContext = 
  [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]$authUrl
```

I have run:

```
 Install-Module -Name AzureAD -AllowClobber
```

then:

```
 Import-Module -Name AzureAD
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext].
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this ?

Update:

```
  $authUrl = "https://login.windows.net/${tenantId}"
  $authContext =
   [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext 
]$authUrl
$cred = New-Object 
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential 
$applicationId,$key
```

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65336363/45375) helps.

Comment: tried that but get the error:      Add-Type : Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target. Exception setting "Path": "Cannot find path 'C:\Program 
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureAD\2.0.2.128\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll' because it does not exist.

Comment: If i look in that path i cant see the dll, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll ?

Comment: From start button type "Edit the System Environmental variables".  Then add to the path variable the path of where the AzureAd\2.0.2.128 modules are located.

Comment: @Melissa: Note that I'm just _guessing_, as I am not an Azure AD user. It looks like this DLL no longer ships with the module, and that is has been replaced by a different one, possibly `Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/how-to/migrate-confidential-client?tabs=daemon

Comment: On a more fundamental note: the [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread) module is [_deprecated_](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/important-azure-ad-graph-retirement-and-powershell-module/ba-p/3848270) in favor of the [`Microsoft.Graph`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/overview) module. A [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/migration-steps) exists.

Comment: Ok so how can i fix this , do i need to change the type ? Do i need to change the path ?

Comment: I have put update code in the question to show how i am using it . Any help would be appreciated , thanks

Comment: Due to lack of subject-matter expertise, I cannot personally assist you any further, but the tag `azure-active-directory` will hopefully attract experts.